# how to avoid or disable default logging of sshj library

Tags: java, logging, sshj

I'm using SSHJ library to transfer files over sftp. I took help from the follwing blog:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-sftp

When I run the program it was throwing some sl4j issues, so I added sl4j dependencies in my project and added the BasicConfigurator in my code `BasicConfigurator.configure();`. Now it is printing everything on console. I want to disable that logging or log the sshj related log to another log file. How can I do that?

Comment: SLF4J don't work alone it need implementation like log4j or logback each of those has configuration files to configure whar are the logs to be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' been a while since I played with this but I think this is the key (and of course this can be done with configuration files):

```
        final Logger app = Logger.getLogger("net.schmizz");
        app.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```